# Why did SQL Server suddenly stop using an obvious index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

In our SQL Server 2005 database we have a table with just over 9m rows. It's an "Order Ledger" to track activity against an order. There is also an associated "type", table with about 13 rows, that is referenced by the `type_id` column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order_ledger](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date_created] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_order_ledger_date_created]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [order_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk1] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_order_ledger_fk]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [fk2] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_order_ledger_fk2]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [description] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [amount] [money] NOT NULL,
    [fee_portion] [money] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_order_ledger_fee_portion]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [studio_id] [int] NULL,
    [qty] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_order_ledger_qty]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_order_ledger] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order_ledger_type](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_order_ledger_type] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have an indices on the `order_id` and `type_id` columns:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [order_ledger_order_id] ON [dbo].[order_ledger] 
(
    [order_id] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [order_ledger_type_id] ON [dbo].[order_ledger] 
(
    [type_id] ASC
)
```

Each order has about 7-10 rows in the `order_ledger` table.

For years, the follow query executed very quickly:

```
SELECT ol.id, ol.amount, olt.name AS type_name
FROM accounting.dbo.order_ledger ol
INNER JOIN accounting.dbo.order_ledger_type olt
ON olt.id = ol.type_id
WHERE order_id = @order_id
```

Starting about a week ago, this query suddenly slowed stopped using the obvious choice for an index, `order_ledger_order_id`. The STATISTICS IO results from that query are as follows:

```
Table 'order_ledger'. Scan count 14, logical reads 27351970, physical reads 28998, read-ahead reads 19889, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'order_ledger_type'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

If I modify the query with a HINT, it returns to normal:

```
FROM accounting.dbo.order_ledger ol
WITH (INDEX(order_ledger_order_id))
INNER JOIN accounting.dbo.order_ledger_type olt
ON olt.id = ol.type_id
WHERE order_id = @order_id
```

```
(7 row(s) affected)
Table 'order_ledger_type'. Scan count 0, logical reads 14, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'order_ledger'. Scan count 1, logical reads 25, physical reads 6, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

If I simplify the query to remove the join, it also execute quickly, even without the hint:

```
SELECT ol.id, ol.amount
FROM accounting.dbo.order_ledger ol
WHERE order_id = @order_id
```

```
(7 row(s) affected)
Table 'order_ledger'. Scan count 1, logical reads 25, physical reads 4, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

I tried rebuilding the `order_ledger_order_id` index as well, and that did not help. Without the hint, the query plan indicates that there is an Index Seek on the `order_ledger` table, but that seek is using an index on the `type_id` column, which the less obvious choice to use and likely the source of the issue.

Any help on why SQL Server 2005 would suddenly shift from using the obvious index on the `order_id` column to using the index on the `type_id` column would be appreciated. I have queries all throughout the middleware that do not have index hints, so I would prefer to fix the underlying issue than add table hints to hundreds of deeply buried queries.

Comment: None of those indexes are covering indexes, so they aren't *that* useful to the data engine, as it will be forced to use a key lookup. These *can* be more expensive that a scan of the clustered index.

Comment: IO statistics are somewhat interesting, but an actual query plan is more useful in trying to diagnose what the issue is. Can you upload both the un-hinted and hinted version to [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? Also, if the preponderance of data access for this table is done via order_id, it might make sense to have that be the clustering key (and have the PK be a non-clustered index). That's a pretty big change but one that might be worth exploring.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and idea. Here are the plans, per your suggestion.

Hinted Plan:   

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJikA2LBo

Unhinted Plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk3RJpISs

Comment: Is there a foreign key between `order_ledger_type` and `order_ledger`? Is that foreign key marked as trusted? The estimated number of rows from joining those two tables in their entirety is 1 for some reason (in your "Unhinted Plan"). Rather than the 9,117,674 that appear in reality as presumably every row in `order_ledger` matches a valid  `order_ledger_type`

Comment: you are on build 9.00.1399.06 - this is the RTM version of SQL Server 2005. So not only are you running on a very outdated and unsupported version but there are a load of bug fixes that you aren't even taking advantage of. Potentially including w.r.t. cardinality estimation.

Comment: @MartinSmith, you are correct, the `type_id` in `order_ledger` always has a match in `order_ledger_type`. I did not have a specific FK defined between those fields, though I am not opposed to adding one if it'll help. I'm not super sure I understand the conveyed advantage other than cascading deletes and updates automatically. Does a Foreign Key help with query plan? (I feel like there must be a good article about that somewhere). And yes, I am well aware that 2005 is waaaaay old. A newer version is out of budget given the $$ that MS wants for a new version that will use all cores.

Comment: Every time you need to "match" something, be it in a join or a key-lookup it has a cost. If the (estimated) cost of doing something adds up too high, SQL Server tends to mess up. "14 types times an order_id index seek and 5.6 rows per id !? I'll take a full scan in reverse order in stead". Try `INCLUDE(amount)` in the `order_ledger_order_id` index  to avoid the key-lookup - maybe it'll help. Otherwise, I'd just go with the hint. In other news, the 14 types are an easy candidate for data to cache in the application - JOINS to get display values almost always mess things up.

Comment: Having had a look at the unhinted plan again, I'll say @MartinSmith has a point. It's curious that the estimated number of rows is one?! Try adding a foreign key to the relation. It helps SQL Server to realize that all rows in `order_ledger` matches a row in `order_ledger_type`. Maybe that will fix the estimates and push it back to the correct plan. With regards to cost, SQL Express is pretty capable these days and free to use in production.

Comment: Not mentioned yet because maybe too obvious, but have you done an `UPDATE STATISTICS` lately on the related tables? (maybe even force it to be a detailed one)

Comment: @deroby I have not done that in a while. I just executed it. What I ended up doing, and I hope I don't regret the decision, was to remove the index on the `type_id` field. Finding and fixing all queries to provide hints has proven too problematic, and removing the index that was distracting the compiler has been a nice interim solution that seems to be working. I really appreciate all the responses. I've grown as a developer because of the responses! Thank you all!!